Are all the Kr+1-free graphs subgraph of a Turan graph?
Let's consider the following statement :
"All the Kr+1-free graphs are subgraph of a Turan graph T(n,r)"
Do you think this statement is correct ? And if so, would you have any idea to demonstrate it ?
Thanks for your help!

You should add some context to this question. Also adding what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck will make this more likely to get answered.

The Turan graph T(n,r) has chromatic number $r$. But a graph that does not contain $K_{r+1}$ might have chromatic number greater than $r$.

The pentagon $C_5$ is triangle-free, but not bipartite. In other words, it does not contain $K_3$ as a subgraph, and it is not a subgraph of $T(n,2)$ for any $n$.

This statement is false even if we restrict it to $r$-chromatic graphs.
Consider a $K_{r+1}$-free graph with chromatic number $r$ and maximum degree $n-1$, such as $K_{1,\lfloor \frac{n-1}{r-1} \rfloor,..., \lceil \frac{n-1}{r-1} \rceil}$. This graph is not a subgraph of Turan graph since it's maximum degree is $\le n-\lfloor \frac{n}{r}\rfloor$.
