Using Turan's theorem to maximize amount of vertices
Turan's theorem gives lower and upper bounds of |E| given that there is no $K_n$ subgraph for some n, but can we use it to maximize (or minimize) amount of vertices in a graph?
For example, let's fix graph of 50 edges with no triangles: $K_3$ graphs. What is the minimum possible number of vertices in given graph?

@MishaLavrov, there was a typo. I fixed 50 edges with no triangles and wanna maximize amount of vertices

Is this question related to this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4919954/are-all-the-kr1-free-graphs-subgraph-of-a-turan-graph In any event, context please.

First of all I will answer your question about the case with $50$ edges and no $K_3$.
Minimal amount of vertices:
Let's denote $ex(n, F)$ as the maximal number of edges in $n$ vertex, $F$- free graph. From Turan's theorem (or in fact from Mantel's theorem) you have $ex(n, K_3) = \left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4} \right\rfloor$. It holds, that $\lfloor x\rfloor \leqslant x$, so if the number $\frac{n^2}{4}$ is less than $50$, then our graph contains some $K_3$. Thus it must be:
$$
\frac{n^2}{4} \geqslant 50 \iff n \geqslant10\sqrt{2} > 14
$$
Thus $n$ must be at least $15$. Now we need to show, that such graph on $15$ vertices exists. Notice that in $K_{8,7}$ (which is complete bipartite graph on $8$ and $7$ vertices) we have $15$ vertices and $8 \times 7 = 56$ edges and it does not contain $K_3$. Thus if we remove $6$ edges it still won't contain $K_3$ and will have exactly $50$ edges.
Maximal amount of vertices:
You can spot that adding new vertices with degree $0$ does not affect the above structure, so in fact we can obtain arbitrarly large number of vertices.

Now lets consider the general case for $K_{r+1}$-free graphs with fixed $|E|$ edges.
First you pick the smallest $n$ with $ex(n, K_{r+1}) \geqslant |E|$ which is possible since $ex(n, K_{r+1})$ is increasing function and grows to infinity as $n$ grows. Then you pick Turan's graph $T_{n,r}$ (which is $n$ vertex, $r$-partite, regular graph) and it satisfies the equation $e(T_{n, r}) = ex(n, K_{r + 1}$) where $e(F)$ denotes the number of edges of $F$. Then you just remove some edges to obtain exactly $|E|$ edges in final graph.
For maximal amount of vertices the argument is the same as previously.

how did you get $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor$ from Turan's theorem?

I mean that my understanding of Turans theorem is: if there is no $K_{k+1}$ subgraph in a graph $G$ then number of edges reaches maximum on k-partite graph construction, with no edges inside of each part. And all these parts have sizes which differ by no more than 1. And I do not understand how we can get your $\frac{n^2}{4}$ value from here

This bound is only for $K_3$ and is also known as Mantel's Theorem. If you consider this construction that you mentioned and check for the two cases of parity of $n$ you will get that result.

It seems like I understand it: lets fix k-partite graph with edges only between these parts (no edges in each part), also sizes of these parts differ by no more than 1 (they are almost equal). Let's count maximum number of possible edges. For example if we had 2-partite graph we would have $\lfloor\frac{n}{2} \rfloor^{2}$ edges. For k-partite graph it's gonna be $\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor^{k}$. So for our task with no $K_{2 + 1}$ subgraphs (triangles) we get $\lfloor\frac{n}{2} \rfloor^{2}$, same what you wrote. Am I right?

Notice that for $k > n$ we have $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor = 0$ so this would mean we have no edges, but obviously there are some. Moreover $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor \neq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor^2$ (you can check it for some odd values of $n$)

How this theorem works: if you take this $T_{n, k}$ (a.k.a Turan's graph) then it is the maximal $K_{k + 1}$-free graph. So you don't count maximal number of possible edges - you count the actual amount of edges.  Also this idea of rising something to the power of $k$ is irrelevant since if you have some part of graph of size, let's say $S$ (here $S \approx \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$) then all of those vertices will be conected to $n - S$ vertices, which gives $S \times (n - S)$ edges, so if you consider all such groups the total amount of edges will be of the order $n^2$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
